# How to show a div for different click events using AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I have 2 export buttons on my page like the following:

```
<li ng-click="someFunction.getDownload()">
<export-button>CSV</export-button>
</li> //EXPORT 1

<li ng-click="someFunction.getDownload()">
<export-button>CSV</export-button>
</li> //EXPORT 2
```

There are 2 `<div>` in my page like this, which shows up when I click on export button:

```
<div ng-show="someFunction.loading" class="alert alert-info">Getting data...</div> //ng-show 1

<div ng-show="someFunction.loading" class="alert alert-info">Getting data...</div> //ng-show 2
```

Right now, when I click either of EXPORT 1 or EXPORT 2, both my `<div>`s appear together.

I want to bind `ng-show` 1 to EXPORT 1 and `ng-show` 2 to EXPORT 2 so that only one of them appear in UI when the respective export is clicked.

How do I do that?

Comment: are you calling the same function with `ng-click` both the times? Can you also show your function `someFunction.getDownload()` and where `someFunction.loading` value is changed/updated

Answer (score 1):

There are honestly a ton of ways you can do this.

### One Possible Solution

One of the easiest ways is to just set a variable to true or false inside your "GetDownload()" function.

1. Set the variable associated with the Export that was clicked to **true** at the start of your function.
2. Feed that variable to your *ng-show* directive

   - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
3. Then reset your Export flag variables to **false** when that function finishes.

### Code

*HTML*

```
<!-- EXPORT 1 BUTTON -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mc.getDownload('exportOne')" ng-disabled="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exporting()">CSV 1</button>

<!-- EXPORT 2 BUTTON-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mc.getDownload('exportTwo')" ng-disabled="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exporting()">CSV 2</button>

<!-- EXPORT 2 PROCESSING -->
<div ng-show="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne" class="alert alert-info">
    <span>EXPORT 1 - Getting data...</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>

<!-- EXPORT 2 PROCESSING -->
<div ng-show="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo" class="alert alert-info">
    <span>EXPORT 2 - Getting data...</span>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
```

*JS*

```
function _getDownload(exportType) {
  switch (exportType) {
    case 'exportOne':
      // set loading flags
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = true;
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = false;
      break;
    case 'exportTwo':
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = false;
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = true;
      break;
  }

  // do work simulation
  $timeout(() => {
    // when work is done, reset flags
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = false;
      vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = false;
  }, 3000)
}
```

### Example

Here's an example Plunk: https://plnkr.co/1AWqwo

I've placed the Flag Variables to toggle inside of an object, but you can keep them separated depending on your use case.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  let app = angular
    .module("myApp", [])
    .controller("MainController", MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ["$scope", "$timeout"];

  function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
    /**
     * John Papa Style Guide
     * https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md
     * */
    let vm = this;

    // scoped variables
    vm.title = " AngularJS: Selectively Toggle Specific DIVs";
    vm.exportLoadingFlags = {
      exportOne: false,
      exportTwo: false,
      exporting: function() {
        return this.exportOne || this.exportTwo;
      }
    }

    // functions hoist
    vm.getDownload = _getDownload;

    // functions
    function _getDownload(exportType) {

      // set loading flags
      switch (exportType) {
        case 'exportOne':
          vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = true;
          vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = false;
          break;
        case 'exportTwo':
          vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = false;
          vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = true;
          break;
      }

      // do work simulation
      $timeout(() => {
        // when work is done, reset flags
        vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne = false;
        vm.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo = false;
      }, 3000)
    }

    // init function
    function init() {
      // initialize stuff
    }

    // INITIALIZE
    init();
  }

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunk</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- JQuery and Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Angular Stuff -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.js"></script>

  <!-- Our Angularjs App -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- ==== MAIN APP HTML ==== -->

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as mc">
  <div class="container" style="padding:1em;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h3>{{ mc.title }}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ==== Solution 1 ==== -->
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label>Solution 1</label>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Set flag variables to true or false to toggle your DIVs.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <hr style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12" style="padding-top:1.5em;background:rgba(131, 149, 167,0.2)">
        <div>
          <ul>
            <!-- Export 1 Directive -->
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mc.getDownload('exportOne')" ng-disabled="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exporting()">CSV 1</button>
            </li>
            <!-- Export 2 Directive -->
            <li>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="mc.getDownload('exportTwo')" ng-disabled="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exporting()">CSV 2</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <!-- Export 1 Processing -->
          <div ng-show="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exportOne" class="alert alert-info">
            <span>EXPORT 1 - Getting data...</span>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
          </div>
          <!-- Export 2 Processing -->
          <div ng-show="mc.exportLoadingFlags.exportTwo" class="alert alert-info">
            <span>EXPORT 2 - Getting data...</span>
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because of same variable using in both div ng-show="someFunction.loading" when you click on button someFunction.loading value became true and both div appears